# SpringMVC: How to mark two inputs invalid?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, validation

I am using SpringMVC in my webapp to handle forms and their validation.

In my Validator I have code like this:

```
@Override
public void validate(final Object target, final Errors errors)
{
    final LoginCommand loginCommand = (LoginCommand) target;
    if (checkCredentials(loginCommand.getLogin(), loginCommand.getPassword()) {
        errors.rejectValue("login", "login.error.invalid");
        errors.rejectValue("password", "login.error.invalid");          
    }
    //..
```

This way I get the  properly rendered invalid whenn filling the cssErrorClass attribute.
Problem now is that the login.error.invalid message is in the error-message list I am going to display twice.

What is the best way to mark two input fields invalid, but only have one message in the error list?
I searched the SpringMVC documentation/api all over and did not find a way to reject a field without supplying a message.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to mark all form as invalid in this case:

```
if (checkCredentials(loginCommand.getLogin(), loginCommand.getPassword()) {
    errors.rejectValue("login.error.invalid");         
}
```

And show it on view by

```
<form:errors />
```

Comment: In general it would work like this with errors.reject("login.error.invalid"). But then the specific <form:input> fields do not get the cssErrorClass style applied to the class-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
<%@ taglib uri="spring.tld" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="spring-form.tld" prefix="sf"%>
```

You must limit the sf:errors tag by placing it in a s:bind tag.  Here is an example (the path is probabaly not correct for your needs, but is fine for this example) that limits the errors to the login field:

```
<s:bind path="loginForm.login">
  <sf:errors/>
</s:bind>
```

Note: I typed this directly into the answer and it's been a while since I used spring mvc.